# RSpec testing a controller instance variable receives a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm aware that `expect(assign(:var))` in controller specs tests that `@var` gets assigned to some value. In my case I want to test if this `@var` receives a specific message. If I do it before `get :action` the assigns returns nil. If I do it after, it is too late to expect the message.

```
# controller
def action
  @var = something
  @var.message
  render :nothing
end

# spec1
expect(assigns(:var)).to receive(:message) # not working, var is nil
get :action

# spec2
get :action
expect(assigns(:var)).to receive(:message) # not working, expectation too late
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking here is test doubles or mocks. You can use those by adding the [rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) gem or another test double gem like [RR](https://github.com/rr/rr).

Once you have one of those (I personally use RR), you can do this (syntax for RR):

```
mock(assigns(:var)).foo
get :action
```

Not 100% sure on the syntax of `rspec-mocks` but it should look something like this:

```
var = double(assigns(:var))
expect(var).to receive(:foo)
get :action
```

You should look at the README for [Message Expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#message-expectations) and [Expecting Arguments](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#expecting-arguments) if you need to add more checks.

Comment: Tried using rspec-mocks but it didn't work, or I couldn't figure out how it should be written: `var = spy(assigns(:var), action: 1); get :action, id: 10; expect(var).to have_received(:action)`

Comment: Unfortunately, `assigns(:var)` will return `nil` if called before the `get :action` and that's the whole point in my question. For this I tried `spy` instead of `double` which didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe try `@var` instead of `assigns(:var)`?

Comment: @var points to instance variables in the spec example not in the controller scope

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable gets assigned and called in the same method in the controller, I don't believe you have a way to catch it in between and mock it.

Instead I usually expect with "any_instance_of" like this:

```ruby
expect_any_instance_of(ClassOfVar).to receive(:message)
```

Comment: Although expecting any instance would work, but it is not safe to assume that any instance could receive the message and the test would pass.

Comment: I agree it wont work in all the cases, and that it isn't perfect, but it works in for me most cases, and it is the only solution to the problem that you are describing, that I am aware of :-)

I am excited myself to see if someone else has the perfect solution to your problem with no downsides, but for now this is the best I have been able to come up with :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently forcing the controller instance variable to expect the messages on. Although this works, but it skips the loading logic (cancan), so I created another test for that:

```
  it "loads and authorizes object" do
    get :action, id: 10
    assert_response :success
  end

  it "calls action on object" do
    controller.instance_variable_set('@var', @my_real_object_or_mock_here)
    expect(@my_real_object_or_mock_here).to receive(:message)
    get :action, id: 10
    assert_response :success
  end
```

I kinda find this solution hacky, but if this answer gets the most votes, I will accept it :)